# How can I reinitialize/override Firefox download preference in Selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, download

This is code I wrote :

```
    public static void main(String args[]){

            FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
            FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
            ffBinary.setTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60));
            ffProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\ComonFiles");
            ffProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            ffProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;" 
                                    + "application/pdf;"
                                    + "application/xml;"
                                    + "text/xml;"
                                    + "application/zip;"
                                    + "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;" + "text/plain;"
                                    + "text/csv");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, ffProfile);


//Some other operations

downloadFile1();
downloadFile2();


    }

public static void downloadFile1()
{

//Click on download button

} 

public static void downloadFile2()
{
           ffProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\WorkingFiles"); 
           //Click on download button

}
```

I want to download **File2** into some separate folder called `C:\\WorkingFiles`  but it does not override download setting even if I am calling set preference again in `downloadFile2()`. It always download all files into `C:\\ComonFiles`. It still using preference  of main function for download.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible since FirefoxDriver uses its options to start its session (see RemoteWebDriver class which is the super class of FirefoxDriver).  Maybe, your alternative is to create a new instance of  FirefoxDriver using a new FirefoxProfile object.

Comment: @ThiagoProcaci - If I create new instance of FF driver then it will again open Firefox :(

Comment: You can minimize this problem by using FF in headless mode: firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless") . You will start FF again but you will not see the window opening.